# How to add opencv window in pygtk?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, opencv, pygtk

I want to make a program in python using pygtk, which would execute my opencv codes, and give output, so that I can show it in GUI. opencv codes are written in C. I want a window/widget in my GUI, which would belong to opencv, so that whenever any event occurs in that widget, like mouse pointer moves in the widget, it should execute my opencv code and show the output image. I am thinking of using threading. But I don't know how to run C codes, especially opencv codes from python. Can you brief me how to proceed ?

Comment: Have you done anything so far?

Comment: my gui is ready. Just need to add opencv.

Comment: Yes, but what _code_ have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay So I figured it out. I used swig bindings from OpenCV 2.1. And I am loading image using

```
image = gtk.Image()
img_pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_data(img.tostring(),
                                          gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,
                                          False,
                                          img.depth,
                                          img.width,
                                          img.height,
                                          img.width*img.nChannels)  

image = gtk.gdk.set_image_from_pixbuf(img_pixbbuf)
```

Where image is IplImage object.